# Apply function over multiple dimensions in the data.table excluding an observation

Tags: r, data.table

I have a following question. My dataset contains information on workers and firms. What I would like to calculate is the number of coworkers of a particular age group across all firms in which worker is employed. I have figured out solution.

Here is the simulated dataset and solution:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(10)

#Define number of observations:
nr_obs <- 10000

#Simulate data:
data <- data.table(
  work_id=sample(seq(1,100), nr_obs, replace=TRUE),
  firm_id=sample(seq(1,100), nr_obs, replace=TRUE)
)

age <- data.table(work_id = unique(data$work_id),
                  age = sample(seq(1,10),10,replace=TRUE))
data <- merge(data,age,by=c("work_id"))
data <- unique(data,by=c("work_id","firm_id"))

# my solution:
data <- data[,nr_young_peers:={V1 = .(list(firm_id));
                               V2=data[which(firm_id %in% unlist(V1))];
                               V3=dim(V2[age>=3&age<=4,][work_id!=.BY[[1]],])[1]},
                               by=c("work_id")]

unique(data[work_id==1,]$nr_young_peers)
## [1] 754
dim(data[which(firm_id %in% data[work_id==1,]$firm_id),][age>=3 & age<=4 & work_id!=1,])[1]
## [1] 754
```

There are two problems with this solution:
1) It does not scale well with the number of observations;
2) I have an intuition that I am doing some repeated operations, which could be avoided.

Comment: If you haven't read the data.table vignettes yet, they're always strongly recommended. They'd explain, for example, why you never need to do `data <- data[, ... := ...]`, probably illustrate an alternative to `dim()` here (which I have never had to use on a data.table), etc.

Comment: @Frank great suggestion and very helpful! Here it was more of a question of how to iterate over two indices and  to exclude observation in one of them (for this specific problem I have another solution).